# use jquery to upload file?

Tags: php, jquery, file, file-upload

How can you use jquery to simply post to a php script the value of a file? I'm assuming the Files array and post array are different, so would I have to use a different method?
ex. would posting
var file = $('fileInput').val();
work?
What data am I supposed to send and how should I send it? Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by `value of a file`? do you want to send the filename of you want to send the contents of the file which by the way is not posiible by plain javascript/jquery you have to use a plugin like uploadify...

Comment: im assuming the actual contents, basically everything needed for move_uploaded_file() to work, or the data sent when a submit button is clicked. is this not natively possible with jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to post files using jquery (html5 browsers supporting FileAPI only, others like IE don't support it):

```
        var PostData = new FormData();

        $('form').find(':file').each(function () {
            var inputName = $(this).attr('name');
            for(var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++){
                PostData.append(inputName + '_' + i, this.files[i]);
            }
        });

        var Request = $.ajax({
            url: 'uploadPage.php',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'post',
            data: PostData,
            processData : false,
            success: function (data){
            }
        });
```